# Calling static method of class loaded via different ClassLoader isn't working. Is this expected?

Tags: java, classloader

I have the following class which uses a simple customer ClassLoader to load a class and then call a static method directly on it:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        MyCustClassLoader loader = new MyCustClassLoader();
        Class<?> c = loader.findClass("classloading.FooObservable");
        Object ob = c.newInstance();
        Method md = c.getDeclaredMethod("addListener", Listener.class);

        FooListener fooListener = new FooListener("app class loader");
//        md.invoke(ob, fooListener); <<< works it I uncomment this.
        FooObservable.addListener(fooListener);

        md = c.getMethod("fooDidSomething");
        md.invoke(ob);
        md.invoke(ob);
        md.invoke(ob);
    }

}
```

My custom class loader looks like this:

```
package classloading;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyCustClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) {
        byte[] bt = loadClassData(name);
        return defineClass(name, bt, 0, bt.length);
    }
    private byte[] loadClassData(String className) {
        //read class
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(className.replace(".", "/")+".class");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteSt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //write into byte
        int len =0;
        try {
            while((len=is.read())!=-1){
                byteSt.write(len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //convert into byte array
        return byteSt.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

The static method in question is defined in class `FooObservable` which contains a list of listeners and a notify method that can be called to notify listeners that something has happened:

```
package classloading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    

public class FooObservable {

        private static List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
        int x = 0;

        public static void addListener(Listener l) {
            listeners.add(l);
        }

        public void fooDidSomething() {
            x++;
            for (Listener l : listeners) {
                l.notify(x);
            }
        }

    }
```

It doesn't seem to work, in that nothing is printed. However, when I uncomment the line `md.invoke` class App above and comment out the static call `FooObservable.addListener`, it works and I see:

```
foo listener (app class loader) notified: 1
foo listener (app class loader) notified: 2
foo listener (app class loader) notified: 3
```

Why is this happening? Is it down to the fact that when the line is uncommented, the static call `addListener` is invoked against `FooObservable` which is loaded using the Java AppClassLoader and as such is reloaded with an empty list of listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
FooObservable.addListener(fooListener);
```

is creating a different instance of FooObservable, created by the default classloader. Because it's a different classloader, it's a totally different object. Calls against the md.<> are against the FooObservable from your class loader. Those are two different instances of the same static class (that's part of the point of classloaders - you can have different instances of the same class).

If instead of calling md.invoke(ob) you called FooObservable.fooDidSomething(), you would see a successful result (from the parent classloader instance).

Without calling md.addListener (the commented out line), the version loaded by your classloader has no listeners.